# Не подключается шрифт в Sass

Tags: css, шрифты, sass

Не подключается шрифт:

```
   @font-face
     font-family: 'CyrillicOld'
     src: url('../fonts/cyrillic_old.ttf')
```

Потом к элементу пишу

```
font-family: 'CyryllicOld', sans-serif
```

Не работает, путь к шрифту правильный, на `sass` пишу.

Comment: Откройте консоль в браузере и смотрите что вам пишут в ошибках и на вкладке Сеть о файле cyrillic_old.ttf.

Comment: Попробуй прописать вот так `url('CyrillicOld.ttf') format('truetype')`

Answer (score 1):

1. Для `sass` путь может быть и правильный, но он должен быть правильным для компилируемого `css`. Проверьте правильно ли указан путь для для компилируемого подключаемого `css` файла.
2. Посмотрите - что написано в консоли? Есть ли ошибка подключения шрифта, если есть, то проблема в пути, и его нужно исправить на тот, что требуется в консоли. Если нет, то проблема с самим шрифтом.
3. Убедитесь, что для требуемого элемента в стилях этот шрифт подключен и не перекрывается другими шрифтами.

Answer (score 1):

```
font-family: 'CyrillicOld'
font-family: 'CyryllicOld'
```

Найди 10 отличий

Comment: Да, это было жестко)